# $_GET filled but $_REQUEST is empty

Tags: php, nginx

I recently installed nginx 1.4.4 and PHP 5.5.8 in Windows 7. I run nginx.exe and php-cgi.exe to run the server and works. When I send a query string in URL, if I `print_r($_GET)` it **has the value** from query string. But if I `print_r($_REQUEST)`, the `$_REQUEST` is only an **empty array**. I have followed some other questions in stackoverflow and all I found is checking request_order and variables_order. in php.ini
Here is my current configuration in php.ini for request_order and variables_order:

```
; This directive determines which super global arrays are registered when PHP
; starts up. G,P,C,E & S are abbreviations for the following respective super
; globals: GET, POST, COOKIE, ENV and SERVER. There is a performance penalty
; paid for the registration of these arrays and because ENV is not as commonly
; used as the others, ENV is not recommended on productions servers. You
; can still get access to the environment variables through getenv() should you
; need to.
; Default Value: "EGPCS"
; Development Value: "GPCS"
; Production Value: "GPCS";
; http://php.net/variables-order
variables_order="GPCS"

; This directive determines which super global data (G,P,C,E & S) should
; be registered into the super global array REQUEST. If so, it also determines
; the order in which that data is registered. The values for this directive are
; specified in the same manner as the variables_order directive, EXCEPT one.
; Leaving this value empty will cause PHP to use the value set in the 
; variables_order directive. It does not mean it will leave the super globals
; array REQUEST empty.
; Default Value: None
; Development Value: "GP"
; Production Value: "GP"
; http://php.net/request-order
request_order="GP"
```

I also found an answer to turn off auto_globals_jit, but it doesn't work.
I have a working installed xampp 1.8.3, which is working in apache server. But when the nginx use xampp's PHP, the `$_REQUEST` is empty too.

Some articles tell to change nginx config to add query_string in fastcgi_params. But the case is the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is empty. But for my case, the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains value. I still try it but it doesn't work either.

What's still missing? Thank you.

**EDIT**

Here is my nginx server configuration (I use Code Igniter, so I follow http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter for the configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  local.dev.com;
    root   html/dev;
    autoindex on;
    index index.php;

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location = /index.php {

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME D:/nginx/html/dev$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `fastcgi_param` configuration from nginx plase.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder Do you mean fastcgi_param in nginx.conf? I have updated the question to include the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter manually builds `$_GET` from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, when used protocol **REQUEST_URI** or **AUTO** (see `$config['uri_protocol']`).

You should modify nginx's config, replace line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

to

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

To solve issue with empty `$_REQUEST`