# $_POST is empty on nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-config

My problem seems similar with [$_POST is empty. Nginx OSx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813701/post-is-empty-nginx-osx) ,  [$_POST is empty in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363846/post-is-empty-in-nginx) and [$_GET filled but $_REQUEST is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622563/get-filled-but-request-is-empty), however I cannot find a solution to work for me there.

Long story short, I cannot get my POST request through to a file named `server.php` on my server.

Let's assume that my `server.php` contains only something like:

```
<?php var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

and my `sites-available/domain.tld` file contains the following:

```
server {

    root /var/www/domain.tld/current/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.tld;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            #limit_except POST {
            #    allow 127.0.0.1;
            #    deny  all;
            #}

            #if ( $request_method !~ ^POST$ ) {
            #    return 405;
            #}

            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            #fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $echo_request_method;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
            fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_BODY $request_body;
            fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;

    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    server_name www.domain.tld;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    if ($host = domain.tld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;

        server_name domain.tld;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Whatever 'POST' request I am making on the `server.php` will just not send any parameters through.

Output of `server.php` would be `array(0) {}`

Some other info:

- Request is made on Request URL: `https://domain.tld/server.php`
- Request Method: `POST`
- Status Code: `200 OK`

A GET request sent like `https://domain.tld/server.php?foo=bar` will show me the correct `foo` variable sent over with a value of `bar`

If needed I can provide details on the request itself. (using `axios` in a `vue` app).

Please advise...

Comment: What's your request `Content-Type` header? I'd like to rule this out as a possibility, but if that header's value is `application/json`, then you'll need to either modify your request or retrieve that data from the `php://input` stream. PHP expects data to be of the `Content-Type` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when storing in request superglobals.

Comment: Also `multipart/form-data` works.

Comment: my `Content-Type` is indeed `application/json;charset=UTF-8`, I'll tackle that in a minute.

Comment: `$echo_request_method` is non-documented variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer may be a bit late, but for the sake of anyone else encountering this same problem:

The issue turned out to be that the `Content-Type` header had the value `application/json`. When PHP parses data to place into the `$_POST` super global, it expects this header to have the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`, the web standard content types. When receiving `application/json` content type data, you must access it from the `php://input` stream.

A solution will end up looking something like this:

```php
$json_string_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded_data = json_decode($json_string_data, true);
```

If your application expects the data to be available in the `$_POST` super global, then the following (admittedly hacky) solution can be used:

```php
$json_string_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded_data = json_decode($json_string_data, true);
$_POST = $decoded_data;
```

Or, for brevity's sake:

```php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```